# A standard program to log command line arguments?

Tags: command-line, logging

Every once in a while, especially when doing make/GNUmake programming, the question emerges *how the command line looked like exactly* that was issued to a program (after make sending it to the shell and the shell preprocessing it). I didn't find a standard way to handle this question, for example logging the verbatim command line into a file and then executing this command line, and I wonder if there is something that I overlooked. Especially for Unix programming I can barely imagine that this isn't standard debugging/logging functionality in the rank of xargs/less/sed/grep.

Comment: You can see all the commands if you use `make -n`, or `make -nB` if the targets have already been built.

Comment: [Bash - Debugging - TecAdmin.net](https://tecadmin.net/tutorial/bash-scripting/bash-debugging/)

Comment: @AFH no, dry-run is _before_ the shell does its expanding. Moreover, dry-running make often doesn't yield the same chain of targets compared to real runs.

Comment: @DavidPostill is -xv output redirectable to some file?

Comment: @Vroomfondel Yes (I think) , if you run `bash -xv script.sh` with some redirection.